# In excel, add up a column so that each row in a new column shows the sum of the other column for all previous values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to add Column A so that it results in Column B, I've tried the Sum and SumIf function in Excel.

```
Column A  :  Column B

0           0
0           0
0           0
4           4
8           12
11          23
6           29
8           37
9           46
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work, but I would expect that in your second row, if you do `=SUM($A$1:A1)` (or whatever your first cell is), and then drag that formula down besides it, it will do what you want.

`$A$1` is always cell `A1` (the top of the list), and the regular `A1` reference will update to always be "the cell to the left", making your sum be "from the first up to the current" element.

---

Alternatively, `=A1` in cell `B1`, and then `=B1+A2` in cell `B2` (and then dragged down as far as necessary) will make column `B` be a running sum of `A`.

Comment: Alternately, `=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1:$A",ROWS($B$1:B1))))` in B1 and copy down. So many ways to skin this cat.